# Finding components using Apache Beam (in parallel)?

Tags: python, graph, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Given the following inputs: (E1, E2), (E2, E3), & (E3,E4). Is it possible to output (E1, E2, E3, E4) using the Apache Beam framework? My goal is to output all the connected components given pairs of elements that match (in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to key (E1, E2) and (E3, E4) with the same key e.g PCollection then use [CoGroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey).